# strsep() causing Segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strsep

I am having a problem with my program in which I am getting a segmentation fault from `strsep()` which was gotten from GDB and has the error message

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00002aaaaad64550 in strsep () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

My code is as follows:

```
int split(char *string, char *commands, char *character) {
    char **sp = &string;
    char *temp;
    temp = strdup(string);
    sp = &temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        commands[i] = strsep(sp, character);
        if (commands[i] == '\0') {
            return 0;
        }
        if (strcasecmp(commands[i], "") == 0) {
            i--;
        }
        printf("%d", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have spent hours trying to solve this problem

The arguments for the function are `("Hello World", "@", "&")`

**EDIT**

So I have managed to get rid of the segment fault by changing the code to

```
int split(char* string, char* commands, char* character) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                commands[i] = strsep(&string, character);
                if(commands[i] == '\0') {
                        return 0;
                }
                if(strcasecmp(&commands[i], "") == 0) {
                        i--;
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

However now I have a new problem with commands returning a null array where every index is out of bounds.

**EDIT 2**

I should also clarify on what I am trying to do a bit so essentially commands is of type `char* commands[100]` and I want to pass it into the function when then modifies the original pointer array and store say `"Hello World"' into commands[0] then I want to modify this value outside the function.

Comment: what is `commands`? Please post an **entire program** that reproduces the problem, including the call to this function.

Comment: You're assigning a pointer to characters to `commands[i]` which is a *char*. Chances are you're doing something that overwrites the pointer that strsep is acting upon.

Comment: I can't try this now so I won't post an answer, but it looks like you'd want to get rid of the first 4 lines (`sp` and `temp` variables), and just call it as `strsep(&string, character)`.  Also check for `string` being set to `null`.

Comment: AFAICS, the seg fault comes from writing to string literals.  `strsep()` tries to modify `Hello World` (at least if you passed a space instead of an `@` sign), and then tries to modify `command` too.  I think you're misusing `strsep()` too.  I would expect to pass `&string` as the first argument, rather than `sp`, even though the value in `sp` is `&string`.  At least, that's a more conventional usage of it.

Comment: Yeah sorry for the mess I was looking at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19048-01/chorus401/806-4422/6jdgkltde/index.html as an example for how to use strsep

Comment: What output do you expect from `split("Hello World", "@", "&")`?  There are no modifiable parameters, and the return value is (in the revised code) always `0`.  Please create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).
That will add a minuscule `main()` function that shows how you're calling the function and processing the output from the function.  Splitting `"Hello World"` on `&` seems like you'd only have one token in the result.

Comment: I would expect just "Hello World" to be stored in commands[0] since there is no &.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of `commands` is inconsistent with the function prototype: the caller passes an array of 100 `char*`, `commands` should be a pointer to an array of `char *`, hence a type `char **commands` or `char *commands[]`. For the caller to determine the number of tokens stored into the array, you should either store a `NULL` pointer at the end or return this number or both.

Storing `commands[i] = strsep(...)` is incorrect as `commands` is defined as a `char *`, not a `char **`.

It is surprising you get a segmentation fault in `strsep()` because the arguments seem correct, unless `character` happens to be an invalid pointer.

Conversely you have undefined behavior most likely resulting in a segmentation fault in `strcasecmp(commands[i], "")` as `commands[i]` is a `char` value, not a valid pointer.

Here is a modified version:

```
// commands is assumed to point to an array of at least 100 pointers
// return the number of tokens or -1 is case of allocation failure
int split(const char *string, char *commands[], const char *separators) {
    char *dup = strdup(string + strcspn(string, separators));
    if (temp == NULL)
        return -1;
    char *temp = dup;
    char **sp = &temp;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 99) {
        char *token = strsep(sp, separators);
        if (token == NULL) // no more tokens
            break;
        if (*token == '\0') // ignore empty tokens
            continue;
        commands[i++] = token;
    }
    commands[i] = NULL;
    if (i == 0) {
        free(dup);
    }
    return i;
}
```

The memory allocated for the tokens can be freed by freeing the first pointer in the `commands` array. It might be simpler to duplicate these tokens so they an be freed in a more generic way.

Comment: The memory allocated via `temp` is leaked — there's no guarantee that the first token starts at the beginning of the string (in general; the sample data is safe on that score).

Comment: In general it worked however it did not solve my new problem where every index of commands is out of bounds.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I fixed the memory leak issue. I noticed it just after posting, but I went out of coverage :)

Comment: @JustinHaindel: does your function still have the incorrect prototype?